# character string to date and time using R

Tags: r, strptime, lubridate

I have date and time quiz due dates and submission times in the following format for about 400,000 rows. The date and time are characters:

```
  Lesson<-data.table(Quiz = c(1:5), 
  Duedate=c("2015-07-29 08:00", "2015-08-05 08:00","2015-08-12 08:00", "2015-08-19 08:00", "2015-08-26 08:00"),
  Datecomp=c("2015-07-30 21:00", "2015-08-04 13:00","2015-08-12 07:59", "2015-08-19 10:00", "2015-08-16 23:00"))
```

I need to convert this to date and time format to use <= to determine which are late.

I have tried using

```
library(lubridate)
Lesson$Duedate<-as.Date(Lesson$Duedate,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

But this cuts off the time which I need.

I have also tried strptime as follows:

```
Lesson$Datecomp<-strptime(Lesson$Datecomp, "%Y%m%d %H%M")
```

But am getting the following error message:

```
   Warning messages:
  1: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
    Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 5 items of column 'Datecomp' (6 unused)
  2: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
    Coerced 'list' RHS to 'character' to match the column's type. Either change the target column to 'list' first (by creating a new 'list' vector length 5 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'character' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.
```

Any assistance as to how to format date and time and specify to Australia/Melbourne time would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
Lesson$Duedate <- as.POSIXct(Lesson$Duedate, tz = "Australia/Melbourne")
Lesson$Datecomp <- as.POSIXct(Lesson$Datecomp, tz = "Australia/Melbourne")
```

You can add `format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"` to these, but you are already in a default format.